# problema al importar un formulario a mi proyecto actual!

Tags: c#, visual

la cuestión es la siguiente en mi proyecto actual estoy trabajando en un formulario con conexión a mysql. todo bien hasta el momento que requiero importar un formulario ya existente, se preguntaran el por que hago ello bueno el formulario a importar ya tiene todos los campos que requiero solo hace falta modificar ciertos itemes para acoplarlos a mi proyecto actual investigando por internete encontre la siguiente opcion

1.-click derecho sobre tu proyecto. 
2.-seleccionas la opcion agregar.
3.-seleccionas la opcion elemento existente.
4.-me abre el buscador y seleciono mi archivo que es el *.cs
5.-me lo agrega a mi formulario y todo bien pero cuando le doy en la opcion diseño me aparece el formulario vacio. cabe mencionar que el formulario que mando llamar ya posee los textbox combobox y botones cierro la aplicacion y la vuelvo abrir pero no me respeta el formulario que mando llamar.

alguien sabra que estoy haciendo mal para que no me mande llamar mi formulario??

cabe mencionar que uso visual estudio 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando agregas el formulario en lugar de agregar solo el .cs selecciona los 3 archivos necesarios para el formulario, .cs, .designer.cs y el .resx
Ejemplo:

form1.cs

form1.Designer.cs

form1.resx